# Starting a journey with smart capture value submition but depending on the field value submitted

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, dataextensions, smart-capture

I have a data extension and a smart capture landing page which submits its value to that DE. Now I would like to trigger a journey when a user fills a form but the extra step would be to check if field value is 'checkValue'.If the field value matches then only I would like to inject them into the journey and if the field value doesn't match than even if the customer fills the form they will not be injected into the journey. Any info would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could inject everyone who fills out the form into the journey, and as the first step, use a decision split to check whether `checkValue` matches the criteria or not:

- if not, they exit the journey
- if it matches, they continue the journey

You need to make sure that the Data Extension you’re using for the form is a part of an Attribute Group in Contact Builder to be able to use it in a journey.

Read more about the decision split activity: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_decision_splits.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Thank you .This solution worked for my issue.